# Azure Batch - Update job priority on CloudJob (.Net)

Tags: .net, azure-batch

I have a project in .Net and im trying to update the job priority of azure batch.

```
   CloudJob job = await batchClient.JobOperations.GetJobAsync(jobId);
    if (job != null)
     {
        job.Priority = jobUpdateRequest.Priority;                 
        job.Commit();                       
     }
```

when i run that, i got an error 'Operation returned an invalid status code 'Conflict'.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the job is in a state where that property cannot be updated/patched. You will need to disable the job first (and ensure the job is in `disabled` state) before updating/patching the property. Then re-enable the job.